# My ROBLOX code regarding a countdown GUI is acting unexpectedly

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local TimerGui=game.StarterGui.TimerGui
local TimerFrame=TimerGui.TimerFrame
local TimerLabel=TimerFrame.TimerLabel


if game.StarterGui.ScreenGui2.Frame.Visible==false then
TimerFrame.Visible=true
print("hey!")
for i= 3,-1, 0 do
    print("hey")
    TimerLabel.Text=i
    wait(1)
    if i==0 then
        break
    end
    print("HEY")
    end
end
```

I tried everything I can think of as a scripting beginner, but it isn't working.
`game.StarterGui.ScreenGui2.Frame.Visible=true` but after clicking a button in another localscript, it turns into false, I don't know why this isn't working.

```
local TimerGui=game.StarterGui.TimerGui
local TimerFrame=TimerGui.TimerFrame
local TimerLabel=TimerFrame.TimerLabel


if game.StarterGui.ScreenGui2.Frame.Visible==false then
TimerFrame.Visible=true
print("hey!")
for i= 3,-1, 0 do
    print("hey")
    TimerLabel.Text=i
    wait(1)
    if i==0 then
        break
    end
    print("HEY")
    end
end
```

script for game.StarterGui.ScreenGui2:

```
local ScreenGui2=script.Parent
local Frame=ScreenGui2.Frame
local player=game.Players.LocalPlayer
local TimerGui=game.StarterGui.TimerGui
local TimerFrame=TimerGui.TimerFrame
local TimerLabel=TimerFrame.TimerLabel

Frame.Start.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(-10, 0,-10, 0), Enum.EasingDirection.Out, Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce, 0.07,false)
Frame.Visible=false
    
    
end)

Frame.Start.TouchTap:Connect(function()

Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(-10, 0,-10, 0), Enum.EasingDirection.Out, Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce, 0.07,false)
Frame.Visible=false
    
=
end)
```

Comment: nvm got it right after trying more! so proud of my noob self

Comment: Can you explain what "not working" meant on this question? Future readers may find the explanation useful.

Answer (score 0):

> local ScreenGui2=script.Parent local Frame=ScreenGui2.Frame local
> player=game.Players.LocalPlayer wait() local
> TimerGui=player.PlayerGui.TimerGui local
> TimerFrame=TimerGui.TimerFrame local TimerLabel=TimerFrame.TimerLabel
>
> Frame.Start.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
> Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(-10, 0,-10, 0),
> Enum.EasingDirection.Out, Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce, 0.07,false)
> Frame.Visible=false         if Frame.Visible==false then
> TimerFrame.Visible=true         print("hey!")       for i= 3,0, -1 do
> print("hey")            TimerLabel.Text=i           wait(1)             if i==0 then
> break           end             print("HEY")        end     end end)
>
> Frame.Start.TouchTap:Connect(function()
>
> Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(-10, 0,-10, 0),
> Enum.EasingDirection.Out, Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce, 0.07,false)
> Frame.Visible=false
>
> end)

after trying i put this

Comment: I wonder if you intended to use code formatting here, and applied quote formatting instead. This seems to have lost the newlines and indentation, and thus it no longer makes sense. Would you fix this?

Comment: Please also add some commentary (in the answer itself) to explain _how_ this fixes the problem you were having. Future readers will find that much easier to learn from than a block of code on its own.